# Streambuilder not working with Firebase query with multiple where clause

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

The following stream works when there's only one where query, but when there's multiple where queries the stream no longer works. Does anyone have any insights to this? Thanks!

```
StreamBuilder(
                        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('activities')
                            .where('userID', isNotEqualTo: currentUserID)
                            .where('audience', isEqualTo: 'Public')
                            .snapshots(),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't combine two queries if one of your queries includes `isNotEqualTo` clause.

You'll have to use a single query (or combine it one by one) on the client side.

Comment: this is the oddest thing